# HTML elements are converted to plain text in laravel Respone::json()

Tags: json, laravel-5

I am using `laravel 5.0` and trying to use html tags in `Response::json()`, but the problem is the html elements are converted to plain text.

```
return Response::json([
    'success' => true,
    'message' => 'click  <a href="#">here<a/>'
]);
```

the output is: click `<a href="#">here<a/>`

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this situation with output json all right. 
I think that you want to display message on your front via javascript?
If yes -  you must append data as HTML, not as plain text

Simple examle with using jQuery: (/testJson resturn json string as in your example)

```
<div id="testBlock"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.post('/testJson').done(function(result){
        jQuery("#testBlock").html(result.message);
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. that was the problem. I hadn't noticed that. thank you